# Can I create .las or .laz files from .hgt, .tiff, .gpx/kml or .asc files?

Tags: lidar, google-earth, las, esri-ascii-raster, hgt

I have got into a golf simulator game and want to recreate my home course. Problem here is that the only import way for height information is a LAZ or LAS file. So I am looking for a way to work around. The Austrian government provides HGT and TIFF files, I tried a few ways but not being able to get it done, I have tried txt2las but I didn't get it done. My last idea what I found googling was to export height information from Google Earth via a KML/KMZ file and then port it to LAS/LAZ.

Did someone already do this and made a tutorial about it? Or am I just thinking too complicated and there is a way easier way?

Files I got from the area I need is the HGT file of the whole region, TIFF files, ASCII (ASC) raster and KML/KMZ export from Google Earth.

Comment: Have a read of https://rapidlasso.com/2020/01/13/converting-rasters-from-inefficient-ascii-xyz-to-more-compact-laz-or-tif-formats/ and see if anything there helps. For the size of a golf course the free version of lastools should be enough; I'm not sure what is happening with licensing as I believe Martin Isenburg is recently deceased.

Comment: It seems that your local golf course is in Australia, depending on the LGA and state better elevation data could be available, Geoscience Australia has 5 metre NEDF raster which suits the purposes of those working on a whole state to national scale project but for a golf course that's quite chunky (and likely out of date), local governments in partnership with state authorities regularly collect LiDAR which is likely to be more recent and much higher density, in some cases 32 pulses per square metre with 4-8 pulses most common, contacting your LGA might prove fruitful and you'd even get trees.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able/willing to code a little, you could create the LAZ file in Python using [laspy](https://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Here is some example code:

```
import laspy
import numpy as np

# generate random xyz point data:
n_points = 100
xyz = np.random.uniform(0, 30, (3, n_points))  # xyz point geometry
rgb = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3, n_points))  # rgb colour
intensity = rgb.mean(axis=0).astype('uint8')  # backscatter amplitude or intensity
n_returns = np.ones_like(intensity, dtype='uint8')  # number of laser returns per pulse
clf = np.copy(n_returns) + 1  # point classification (e.g. 2 = ground, 5 = veg)

# create the las file:
las = laspy.file.File('test.las', mode='w', header=laspy.header.Header())
las.header.offset = xyz.min(axis=1)
las.header.scale = [1, 1, 1]

# set point attributes:
las.X = xyz[0]
las.Y = xyz[1]
las.Z = xyz[2]
las.intensity = intensity
las.r = rgb[0]
las.g = rgb[1]
las.b = rgb[2]
las.return_num = n_returns
las.num_returns = n_returns
las.raw_classification = clf

# close file:
las.close()
```

If the [ASCII raster contains tabular XYZ coordinates](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html), you should be able to easily read the XYZ coordinates directly in Python (see [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) library). Once you have the XYZ data as numpy arrays, you can write them to the las file as shown above.

You probably don't need to bother with other parameters (rgb values, intensity, point classification), but I have included them here for illustrative purposes just in case you want to do something fancy like classify trees around the golf course!